# How can I find out which enchantments that I know?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, there is an Enchanting mechanic. You learn an enchantment by disenchanting something with that type of enchantment. Other than by visiting an Arcane Enchanter, is there a way to find out which enchantments that I've learned? This will help me by reducing the amount of enchanted weapons that I hoard by letting me dispose of items whose enchantments I already know.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to know which enchantments you have learned other than visiting an arcane enchanter or keeping track of it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Or there is a Mod on Skyrim Nexus that appends the name of items that are currently disenchantable by your character with a (U). it's called "Unknown Enchants".
Link: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/32380/?

Comment: This mod is no longer available.